# How to open property pane in a SPFx webpart without going in edit mode?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-custom-property-pane

Is there a way to open the property pane without going into edit mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by calling the `open()` method of the Property Pane which can be accessed via the web part's context property:

```
this.context.propertyPane.open();
```

You can call it on a button click event and it will open the property pane without manually opening the page in edit mode.

Comment: I will give it a try.

Comment: This will not work in production (anymore), because the property pane is only initialized when you go in edit mode and open it yourself. A possible bypass is to call `this.context.propertyPane.openDetails()` before `this.context.propertyPane.open()` that is a sort of hack I addressed in my question here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/281326/how-to-use-the-webparts-property-pane-to-edit-data-in-read-mode/281332#281332